# Why does a HttpClient GET time out for Staples.com?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying a pretty simple GET request for a domain in a .NET Core 2.0 console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.staples.com");
}
```

This times out every time, throwing a web exception.

I can visit the website https://www.staples.com in my web browser or execute a GET request in postman without a problem, returning in < 1s.

I can even do a simple curl request on the domain and it works fine:

```
curl https://www.staples.com
```

Another domain I found the same problem on is https://www.safeco.com/

I have even tried adding some headers to make it seem like this a Chrome browser request, but made no difference:

```
message.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) " +
  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36");
message.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
message.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
message.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
message.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;" +
  "q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
```

Any other URL that I tried not on those domains seems to work fine. Why are these two domains timing out with HttpClient requests?

Comment: I assume when you add those headers you are `SendAsync`'ing an HttpRequestMessage and not the code you have shown in the question?

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, I'm just pulling snippets instead of being overly verbose.

Comment: How are we supposed to know for sure why this is happening? My guess would be to prevent scrapers, but only Staples could answer that.

Comment: @DavidG What is the difference between a postman request with the same parameters and a HttpClient request? Why would one work and not the other?

Comment: It's all just bytes flying across the wire. If one works and the other doesn't, it's because the one that doesn't work is sending different requests or not doing a good job of handling responses.

Comment: Not sure about Postman but I just used Fiddler to mimic my exact browser connection and it worked fine there.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, the point is that HttpClient is not working. Other means of requesting it are working fine. Even a basic `curl https://www.staples.com`

Comment: Please paste the full HTTP request created by `HttpClient`, including full headers, and a known good working request, into the question for analysis.

Comment: @Amy That's not necessary. The above code demonstrates the problem. The headers snippet was just another attempt to show that it made no difference with or without.

Comment: Open fiddler and compare what exactly is sent by postman and by your .NET application. If that is completely identical - include full request in question.

Comment: @kspearrin I disagree, we can't help you without it.  We need to see what is different on the wire before we can suggest changes to your code.  *Something* is different between a working request and a non-working request.  We need the requests to see what that is -- not your code.

Comment: @kspearrin Were the additional domains that worked HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: @Nkosi I've tried both with success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly some sort of connection filtering on their end to prevent scraping but only their IT department would ever be able to confirm that. You can get it working by mimicking a browser and sending the correct headers. It seems this site requires a minimum of:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: xxx
```

For example:

```
static async Task<string> MainAsync()
{
    //Added this to decompress the gzip encoded response
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip;

    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Get, 
        RequestUri = new Uri("https://www.staples.com"),
        Version = new Version(1, 1)
    };

    request.Headers.Connection.Add("keep-alive");
    request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.StringWithQualityHeaderValue("en-GB"));

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: It also turns out that adding a user agent such as `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36` also causes the request to be blocked.

Comment: for me only setting a user agent the same as curl has already allowed the request to pass

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but not appropriate for comment either - Maybe you can glean something from the network trace by adding this to your config. Just change the value of `initializeData` to a writable location, make a request, then look at the output. It ain't pretty but there may be a clue.

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="102400" tracemode="includehex">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="System.Net" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\somewhere...\networkErr.log" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: You could have made a comment containing a link to this code.  IMO that's the optimal way of handling this.